# How to get to Courcle from Filia in Mabinogi?

Tags: mabinogi

I'm coming from Filia so I can't tak the raft. I also have no bird, so I can't fly. What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Filia in the Northern part of the map there is an area called Errans Canyon. Travel to the top left of Errans Canyon with a L-Rod.  There should be some crumbled looking pillars. use the L-Rod there and a bridge should appear that you can cross to get to Courcle.

Comment: I did that already, I need to cross the Suytu River

Comment: To cross the river go to the Cenae Meadows words on the map and next to the C in Cenae should be some Hippos crossing the river. you can ride them across the river.

Comment: I've tried that, but I can't mount them. The wiki also said they are un-mountable

Comment: The ones crossing the river are mountable. I am not near my home computer so I cant try it to tell you exactly how to mount them but I think you can right click their name and mount/ride should be an option. Also only try it when they stop moving.

Comment: oh also in regards to the wiki saying they are not mountable. It was talking about the enemy hippos not the NPC (as the wiki calls them) hippos. Here is the link to it http://wiki.mabinogiworld.com/view/Hippo_(NPC)